# I'm trying to require a qurey in my request only if another qurey is sent

Tags: laravel

In my search function

I'm trying to add 2 more query  sortBy and sortOrder

They are but not required how ever if he did send the sortBy he must send sortOrder as well and same thing in reverse

So i found a way by doing this

```php
If (!in_array($request->sortBy,['price']) ||(!in_array($request->sortOrder,['asc','desc']))){
Throw ValidationExeption::withMessage([
'error'=>'my validation error here '
]);
}
```

However i wanna know if  there is a way to do that in the validation without doing all of this logic in my controller

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that

```
'sortBy' => 'othervalidation|required_with:sortOrder',
                'sortOrder'=>'othervalidation|required_with:sortBy',
```